# Play framework update version from 2.3 to 2.4 dependency injection support

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I’m starting migration play from 2.3, 2.4. So after update of plugin.sbt with new version: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")` during `sbt clean compile` happened an error (in Global.scala) linked to a method **getControllerInstance** in the instruction:  **instance.getOrElse(super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass))**

> instance.getOrElse(super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass)) .
> /Global.scala:244: value getControllerInstance is not a member of
> play.api.mvc.WithFilters with play.api.GlobalSettings [error]
> instance.getOrElse(super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass))
> [error]                              ^

The problem seems to be related to the fact that play 2.4 does not support dependency injection which is out of the box. Not wanting to use Guice, how can I fix this?

Comment: Which error? Did you read the migration notes?

Answer (score 0):

Read the migration guide and especially the section [Dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Dependency-Injection)

You have to use DI (or compile time DI). Guice is the default framework proposed by Play but you can use another one if you don't want Guice.

Comment: I see that problem came from securesocial library, the version 2.4 use a different approach for DI, but how can I solve it ?

Comment: If you are talking about https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial, the library seems unmaintained but you could try latest version (3.0-M8) which from the changelog should be compatible.